# can I create lib or external package from part of namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, api, winapi

I have two projects. one as webapi, second as standalone desktop application. only common thing are data models. 
In my webapi i got namespace `Api.Models` and i dekstop I got `Desktop.Models`

Can I export from my Api the `Api.Models` as a lib and include it in `Desktop` ? If yes how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create another class library project Common.Models, then move your Api.Models to this project and reference it from both WebApi application and Desktop application